# Android R8 compilation - multiple warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, android-r8

I am using R8 version r8-3.3.28.jar for building android application and getting bunch of warnings which I cannot understand.

Can anyone help here?

Invalid stack map table at 29: tableswitch
0: L?
1: L?
default: L?, error: Source locals {0:Initialized(RL.otbgvycijjopvme.ojojoo),1:Initialized(java.lang.String),2:Initialized(int),3:Initialized(int),4:Initialized(int[]),5:Initialized(RL.otbgvycijjopvme.oooojo),6:Initialized(int)} have different local indices than {0:Initialized(otbgvycijjopvme.ojojoo),1:Initialized(java.lang.String),2:Initialized(int),3:Initialized(L.otbgvycijjopvme.oooojo),4:top,5:Initialized(int),6:Initialized(int[]),7:Initialized(int)}.
Warning in .aar:classes.jar:otbgvycijjopvme/jojojo.class at L/otbgvycijjopvme/jojojo;bf0066ffff(Ljava/lang/String;CC)Ljava/lang/String;:
Invalid stack map table at 5: goto L?, error: Source locals {0:Initialized(otbgvycijjopvme.jojojo),1:Initialized(java.lang.String),2:Initialized(int),3:Initialized(int),4:Initialized(int[]),5:Initialized(otbgvycijjopvme.oooojo)} have different local indices than {0:Initialized(otbgvycijjopvme.jojojo),1:Initialized(java.lang.String),2:Initialized(int),3:Initialized(int),4:top,5:top,6:top,7:top,8:Initialized(int[]),9:Initialized(otbgvycijjopvme.oooojo)}.

Compilation with R8-2.1.75 worked fine.

Comment: Looks as if you have some input AAR, where the classes.jar as the class otbgvycijjopvme/jojojo.class, and that class has issues. Please open an issue on https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938, and share the class files if possible.